# A minor clarification on completion of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This is from Karatzas + Shreve

Definition: The stochastic process $X$ is adapted to filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ if, for each $t\geq 0$, $X_t$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable random variable.

### Obviously every process $X$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t^X$. Moreover if $X$ is adapted to $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ and $Y$ is a modification of $X$, then $Y$ is adapted to $\mathcal\{F_t\}$ provided that $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains all the $P$-negligible sets.

My question is: Modification means $P(X_t=Y_t)=1$ for all $t\geq 0$. Surely we need 'how $X$ differs from $Y$' to be in $\mathcal{F}_0$? why is this necessary a $P$-negligible set?

I don't even see why such information need to be measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ - consider the example, $X_t=0$ for all $t\geq 0$ and $Y_t= 0$ for all $t\geq 0$, except at $t=T$, $Y_t=1$, where $T$ has an exponential distribution under $P$.

suppose $X_t$ in this circumstance is adapted to a filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$, under whatever probability measure $P$,  then what should be the $P$-negligible sets which belong to $\mathcal{F}_0$ here?

Comment: @ Lost1 : I am not sure what is your question really about, could you please restate it more clearly ? Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge try again. please let me know how else it can be improved

Comment: Are you asking why $\{X_t=Y_t\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t$ provided that $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains all $P$-null-sets?

Comment: I think maybe you should make precise what event you mean by "how $X$ differs from $Y$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your example, note that $Y_t^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{T = t\}$.  Since $T$ is exponentially distributed under $P$, $P(T=t) = 0$, hence $\{T = t\} \in \mathcal{F}_0$ by assumption.  Also, $Y_t^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{T = t\}^c$ which is also in $\mathcal{F}_0$ because it is a $\sigma$-field.  So $Y_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_0$-measurable; in particular it is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable.

Comment: An addition question, if you don't mind. what does it mean by an $P$-neglible? It says also in the book 'Note that this requirement is not the same as saying $\mathcal{F}_0$ is complete, since some of the $P$-neglible may not be in the completion of $\mathcal{F}_0$? thank you again